# Metapost bounding box and penwidth

Tags: metapost, luamplib

When clipping a picture to a bounding box in metapost, extra space outside of the drawn area is included.  When this extra space is removed with `bboxmargin := 0;` it appears that the picture is clipped to the center of the bounding box, i.e. if the bounding box is drawn, then the picture is clipped to the center of the penstroke, and consequently half of the penstroke is chopped off.  Thus, to retain all of the penstroke (and nothing more) it seems to be required that `bboxmargin` be set to half the width of the current pen.

[image]

As in the second fig below, I might have found a sort of way to obtain the width of the penstroke (sometimes it is exact as with the default pen of width `.5bp` and sometimes an approximation if the pen is scaled, zoom in on the blue rectangle to see some bits poking out).
[image]

**Is there a better way to clip exactly to the drawn area?  If not, is there a better way to obtain the width of the current pen?**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
    \mplibcodeinherit{enable}
    \mplibnumbersystem{double}

  \begin{document}
    \begin{mplibcode}

        path p,q;
        picture pica,picb;
        u:=100;
        p = unitsquare scaled u;
        q = u*(.5,1.2)--u*(.5,-.2);
        pickup pencircle scaled 4bp;
        pica:=image(draw p; draw q;);
        picb:=pica;

        beginfig(0);
            pickup pencircle scaled 4bp;
            draw pica;
            interim bboxmargin := 0;
            clip pica to bbox p;
            draw pica withcolor red;
        endfig;

        beginfig(1);
            pickup pencircle scaled 4bp;
            z0=penoffset left of currentpen;
            show(z0);
            show(x0++y0);
            interim bboxmargin:=x0++y0;
            clip picb to bbox p;
            draw picb withcolor blue;   
        endfig;
    \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undocumented in the `metapost` manual, but documented in the `metafont` book on page 8 of chapter 2 are `top`, `bot`, `lft` and `rt`.  These are used in such a way that

```
bot z0=origin;
```

defines the position of the point `z0` such that when drawn with the current pen, the bottom of the penstroke lies at the origin.  Thus, e.g. the height of the current pen can be obtained from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
    pickup pencircle scaled 4bp;
    bot z0=origin;
    penheight=2(ypart z0);
    show(penheight);
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```